# How to get CreatedBy SmallPhotoURL in remoteObjects?

Tags: remote-objects

I have a custom object (Incident__c) and I want to retrieve the object's creator's SmallPhotoURL using remoteObjects. I know that I need to make a formula for it, however I can't figure out what is field I need. I keep getting errors for a wrong field when I tried any of these:
`CreatedBy.SmallPhotoURL`
`CreatedBy.Profile.SmallPhotoURL`

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case where unfortunately even formula field will not work since SmallPhotoURL field is not accessible via formula .

In order to resolve this you will need another remoteObject

You can use Where clause in your remoteObjectModel

```
<apex:remoteObjects >
<apex:remoteObjectModel name="User" jsShorthand="user" fields="Name,Id,SmallPhotoURL">
    <apex:remoteObjectField name="SmallPhotoURL" jsShorthand="photoURL"/>
</apex:remoteObjectModel>
```

```
var ct = new RemoteObjectModel.user();
ct.retrieve( 
{ where: { 
    Id: {eq: UserId}//Note here dynamically populate UserId
  }
 limit: 1 
},  

function(err, records) { 
    if (err) { 
        alert(err); 
    } else { 
        console.log(records.length); 
        console.log(records[0]); 
    } 
} 
);
```

The other way would be to use AJAX call using sforce

```
function getOwnerPhoto (userId){
sforce.connection.sessionId ="{!$Api.Session_ID}";
 var result= sforce.connection.query("select SmallPhotoUrl from User where Id = ' "+ userId+" ' ");
  var records = result.getArray("records");

  document.write("<img src='"+records[0].SmallPhotoUrl+"' alt='Owner Photo'  width=48 height=48 />");

}
```

Don't forget to include this library in case you use AJAX sforce calls

```
<script src="../../soap/ajax/24.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't there a way to expose the small photo or any other photo?

Comment: The above is the only way to expose the photoURL.

Comment: Not even if I manually write to SOQL? I have to do a separate call just for the user?

Comment: You can create a getter method and return that as SOQL .All of these are same .